# Transact SQL date query returning no results

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

From my code, I call an SP using:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_getnotes"))
{
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@ndate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value
                  = Convert.ToDateTime(txtChosenDate.Text);
  cmd.CommandType = commandType;
  cmd.Connection  = conn;

  var dSet = new DataSet();
  using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter { SelectCommand = cmd })
  {
    adapter.Fill(dSet, "ntable");
  }
}
```

The Stored Procedure itself runs a simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM tblNotes WHERE DateAdded = @ndate
```

The problem is no records are returned! `DateAdded` is a `smalldatetime` column.

When I change the query to the following, it works:

```
SELECT * FROM tblNotes WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, DateAdded))) = @ndate
```

Why is this happening? This change affects the entire application and I'd like to find the root cause before getting into changing every single query... The only changes we made are to use parameterized queries and upgrade from SQL Server 2005 to 2008.

TIA.

Comment: what's the contents of 'commandType' ??

Comment: What is the value of `txtChosenDate.Text` ?

Comment: @Marc: the issue is it doesn't return anything for any given date.

Comment: @MitchWheat: That's a function parameter... Would be `CommandType.StoredProcedure` in this case.

Comment: I know what it is, lol! Thx for telling us what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`smalldatetime` has a time portion which needs to match as well.

Use this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tblNotes
WHERE   dateAdded >= CAST(@ndate AS DATE)
        AND dateAdded < DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(@ndate AS DATE))
```

`SQL Server 2008` and above also let you use this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tblNotes
WHERE   CAST(dateAdded AS DATE) = CAST(@ndate AS DATE)
```

efficiently, with the transformation to a range performed by the optimizer.

Comment: +1 Alternatively, if you are only interested in the date, you could change the column to be a [date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) type as of SQL 2008 (it has no time).

Comment: @Quassnoi - Actually that can use an index (and I think you wanted `=` not `>=` on the second one) . SQL Server will add a compute scalar to the plan with start and end of range so it is similar to the first one.

Comment: The second query doesn't work with `=` or with `>=`. The first works fine though. Thanks!

Comment: @Jim - Doesn't work in what way? Do you get an error message? `CAST(dateAdded AS DATE) = CAST(@ndate AS DATE)` should work fine if you are indeed on 2008.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2008 now has a DATE data type, which doesn't keep the time porttion like SMALLDATETIME does.  If you can't change the data type of the column, then you'll have to truncate when doing the compare, or simply cast to DATE:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    tblNotes 
WHERE   cast(dateAdded as date) = @ndate
```

Comment: The first one isn't sargable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know SQL Server but from Oracle experience I'd suspect you're comparing a date time with a date, eg 01/01/2012 01:01:01 against 01/01/2012.